# Is it possible to interpolate $e^n$ in more than one way?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, exponential-function, interpolation

The most basic definition of exponentiation is repeated multiplication, $$e^n = e \cdot e \cdot  \cdot  \cdot  \cdot  e$$ $n$ times

However, if $n$ is a rational number such as $2.4$, this definition breaks down. One way we've been able to interpolate the function $e^x$ to include all real values is by using infinite series $$e^x = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n!}$$

My question is, is it possible to find another function $f$ which is smooth over all the reals and agrees on integer values with $e^x$ but disagrees on rational values?
If it exists, could we use such a function to completely rewrite/overhaul a huge portion of all the math that exists today?

Comment: it is an exercise in Ahlfors that, given a sequence with no finite accumulation point, such as the positive integers, we may construct an entire function with values we prescribe. If you keep the usual values for $e^n$ but then prescribe $f(1/2) = 17,$ you get something new.

Comment: Find a smooth and continuous function that agrees on the integer values? Of course,  Many.  The rewrite and overhaule a huge portion of math that exists?  Not a chance.  For one thing such a function wouldn't satisfy $f(x + y) = f(x)f(y)$

Comment: Ovi, entire means holomorphic on the entire plane. In particular, continuous.

Comment: I wouldn't say the definition "breaks down" at 2.4.  As $e^{n + m} = e^ne^m$ it follows that $(e^{2.4})^5$ would $= e^{12}$ so the definition extends to $\sqrt[5]{e^{12}}$ and for rational $e^{p/q} = \sqrt[q]{e^p}$.  And for irrational $e^x = \sup \{e^r | r \le x; r \in \mathbb Q\}$ are well defined extensions and the only definitions that maintain $e^{x + y} = e^xe^y$

Comment: If $r = \frac{n}{m}$ is rational then $e^{\frac{n}{m}}$ is defined as the number that when taken to the $m$'th power gives us $e^n$. The simple definition of exponentiation you mention can therefore be extended to all rationals. From here we only need to demand continuity to get a uniqely defined function on all the reals numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of interesting ways to tackle this.  As @KayK. shows us, for any periodic function $f(x)$ over the integers not identically equal to one, then $f(x)e^x$ will satisfy your problem.

As @fleablood mentions, we can get a more interesting function.  Unlike the previous example, we can not only keep up with $e^x$ over integers, but we can also maintain some properties of $e^x$ and equal $e^x$ over the rationals.  For example, consider any function that satisfies

$$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y),~~f(1)=e,~~f(x)>0\forall x\in\mathbb R$$

It then follows trivially that $f(n)=e^n$ for $n\in\mathbb N$.  What's more, we can even show that $f(x)=e^x$ for all $x\in\mathbb Q$.  What we can't show is that $f(x)=e^x$ for $x\in\mathbb R$.  Indeed, assign $f(\pi)=3$ and you'll find this doesn't affect $f(x)$ over the rationals.

However, our previous attempt produce a discontinuous function.  (You'll find with the condition of continuity, $f(x)=e^x$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.)

Answer (score 2):

I believe there are tons of such functions. One of them is:

$$e^x \cos (2\pi x)$$